# What are the minimum requirements on X and Y for $\mathbb P(\vert X \vert < \epsilon)>\mathbb P(\vert X +Y\vert < \epsilon)$ to hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Imagine I have to continuous and independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $\mathbb E(X) =0$ and $Y>0$ a.s.

Now under which circumstances can I assume that $\mathbb P(\vert X \vert < \epsilon)>\mathbb P(\vert X +Y\vert < \epsilon)$ to hold  for any $\epsilon>0?$

If $X>0$ then obviously the second probability implies the first probability; If $X<0$, however, is gets a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $$\mathbb P(|X|<\epsilon) > \mathbb P(|X+c| < \epsilon)$$ for any $c>0$, then you also have the inequality you want. For some $Y$, maybe you can get the inequality you want without also having this inequality for every $c>0$, but I suspect this would lead to very awkward conditions on $Y$.

One sufficient condition is for $X$ to have a unimodal distribution centered at $0$. (That is, the PDF of $X$ is increasing at negative values and decreasing at positive values.) In fact, we don't need the "decreasing at positive values" half of being unimodal.

Comment: I already thought of something like that, thank you very much